# Store complete request in a PHP variable

Tags: php, http

I'm creating a framework in PHP, and I need to get the complete raw request done by the browser. So I want something like this in a variable:

```
POST /lolzorz/xD HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: localhost\r\n
User-Agent: UserAgentHere/1.0.00\r\n
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n
Content-Length: 0\r\n
\r\n
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\r\n
<request>\r\n
<question1 param="value" />\r\n
<question2 param="value" />\r\n
<question3 param="value" />\r\n
</request>\r\n
```

Is this possible?

My server information:

- Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.2)
- Apache2
- PHP 5 running as a module

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think php can get hold of the headers part of the raw input stream. (getallheaders()/[apache     _request_headers()](http://docs.php.net/apache_request_headers) has already been mentioned).
But at least you can read the raw post data via the [php://input stream](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the server headers from another web page, then use the [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) function.

If you mean the headers from the user request of the page, you can use the [`apache_request_headers()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) function. Though as kon says, the preferred method is doing this:

```
<?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>
```

You need to make sure you have the `always_populate_raw_post_data` option on in your php.ini.

Comment: i have read it's preferrable to use file_get_contents("php://input"); to get the raw request data.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you have to manually put this together using the $_SERVER vars and the contents of

```
print_r(getallheaders());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the request headers with [apache_request_headers](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)